# Is it risky to use a submitted but not approved PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: cordova, mobile

In my next Mobile Application , I am planning to use "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.2.0",

in the description section , it was clearly mentioned that this plugin is "Submitted and waiting for approval at PhoneGap Build" .

My question about the submitted but not approved phonegap plugins, is it risky to use them ?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap Build plugins are deprecated, so don't worry about it not being approved. Just use the npm version of the plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" source="npm">
  <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="mycoolapp" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Just replace `mycoolapp` with your own url scheme you want to use